# Boost: include path in windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, boost

Im trying to install in windows (64bit 7/8): http://multineat.com/ which is c++ with python binding.

I've already have vs2008/vc++9 installed and Boost installed (Boost is installed with the windows installer for msvc9)

but when I run

```
python setup.py install
```

It shows

```
fatal error c1083, cannot open include file: 'boost/xxxx'
```

I read from the get start docs of Boost that I can link the boost libraries in Visual studio or through command line by calling cl.exe

But the thing is to install multiNEAT I call 'python setup.py install' directly, without using VS2008 or call cl.exe directly in cmd.

I also tried to add directory of boost in PATH in environment variables, but no luck. Another method would be to hard code every single boost library absolute directories, which would be painful to do and to use.

Is there a way to allow the compiler get the include file from boost folder without using vs2008 or cl.exe in cmd?

I am thinking to do some thing in environment variables, but any method would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: @cgohlke It seems previous comments are missing, anyway, it's really helpful, thank you very much! http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#multineat

Comment: Hi @cgohlke, I built boost 1.58 with [bootstrap] [.\b2] and built boost,python with [.\b2 --with-python] and [set include = boost_root] and [set LIB = boost_root\stage\libs]    but it gives me link.exe error c1181" cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib'". Did I set any link wrong or I build it wrong? Spent the whole day trying to figure it out, no luck. Could you suggest me some solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You should put the boost library in the include folder of your VS, here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include`

Or here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt`

I know it is an old question but maybe this will help someone in the future. :)